# Different css styles for grid and for list with WooCommerce Grid / List toggle

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with this **WooCommerce Grid / List toggle plugin**.
On my [clients website](http://tilambi.eu/shop/) price of products is positioned with css `position: absolute;`. It works fine in grid view. But when I switch to list view, the price is overlapping other text. I tried to edit position of price (with `top: 10px;` forexample) but it changed also the position of price in grid view.
So I want to use php `if` statement in header and `echo` the proper position in `<style>` according to grid view or list view was chosen. 
The problem I have is that I don't know which function should I use. Or which variables should I compare, according to which view was chosen.

Here is the code of plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Grid / List toggle
Plugin URI: http://jameskoster.co.uk/tag/grid-list-toggle/
Description: Adds a grid/list view toggle to product archives
Version: 0.4.0
Author: jameskoster
Author URI: http://jameskoster.co.uk
Requires at least: 3.3
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: wc_list_grid_toggle
Domain Path: /languages/
*/

/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    /**
     * Localisation
     **/
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'wc_list_grid_toggle', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );

    /**
     * WC_List_Grid class
     **/
    if (!class_exists('WC_List_Grid')) {

        class WC_List_Grid {

            public function __construct() {
                // Hooks
                add_action( 'wp' , array( $this, 'setup_gridlist' ) , 20);

                // Init settings
                $this->settings = array(
                    array(
                        'name' => __( 'Default catalog view', 'wc_list_grid_toggle' ),
                        'type' => 'title',
                        'id' => 'wc_glt_options'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => __( 'Default catalog view', 'wc_list_grid_toggle' ),
                        'desc_tip'  => __( 'Display products in grid or list view by default', 'wc_list_grid_toggle' ),
                        'id'        => 'wc_glt_default',
                        'type'      => 'select',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'grid'  => __('Grid', 'wc_list_grid_toggle'),
                            'list'  => __('List', 'wc_list_grid_toggle')
                        )
                    ),
                    array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'wc_glt_options' ),
                );

                // Default options
                add_option( 'wc_glt_default', 'grid' );

                // Admin
                add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_image_options_after', array( $this, 'admin_settings' ), 20 );
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_catalog', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ) );
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_products', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ) );
            }

            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /* Class Functions */
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            function admin_settings() {
                woocommerce_admin_fields( $this->settings );
            }

            function save_admin_settings() {
                woocommerce_update_options( $this->settings );
            }

            // Setup
            function setup_gridlist() {
                if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() ) {
                    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'setup_scripts_styles' ), 20);
                    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'setup_scripts_script' ), 20);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $this, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 30);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $this, 'gridlist_buttonwrap_open' ), 9);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $this, 'gridlist_buttonwrap_close' ), 11);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $this, 'gridlist_hr' ), 30);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', array( $this, 'gridlist_cat_desc' ) );
                }
            }

            // Scripts & styles
            function setup_scripts_styles() {
                if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() ) {
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'grid-list-layout', plugins_url( '/assets/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'grid-list-button', plugins_url( '/assets/css/button.css', __FILE__ ) );
                }
            }
            function setup_scripts_script() {
                if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() ) {
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'cookie', plugins_url( '/assets/js/jquery.cookie.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'grid-list-scripts', plugins_url( '/assets/js/jquery.gridlistview.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
                    add_action( 'wp_footer', array(&$this, 'gridlist_set_default_view') );
                }
            }

            // Toggle button
            function gridlist_toggle_button() {
                ?>
                    <nav class="gridlist-toggle">
                        <a href="#" id="grid" title="<?php _e('Zobrazit mřížku', 'wc_list_grid_toggle'); ?>">&#8862; <span><?php _e('Zobrazit mřížku', 'wc_list_grid_toggle'); ?></span></a><a href="#" id="list" title="<?php _e('Zobrazit seznam', 'wc_list_grid_toggle'); ?>">&#8863; <span><?php _e('Zobrazit seznam', 'wc_list_grid_toggle'); ?></span></a>
                    </nav>
                <?php
            }

            // Button wrap
            function gridlist_buttonwrap_open() {
                ?>
                    <div class="gridlist-buttonwrap">
                <?php
            }
            function gridlist_buttonwrap_close() {
                ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }

            // hr
            function gridlist_hr() {
                ?>
                    <hr />
                <?php
            }

            function gridlist_set_default_view() {
                $default = get_option( 'wc_glt_default' );
                ?>
                    <script>
                        if (jQuery.cookie('gridcookie') == null) {
                            jQuery('ul.products').addClass('<?php echo $default; ?>');
                            jQuery('.gridlist-toggle #<?php echo $default; ?>').addClass('active');
                        }
                    </script>
                <?php
            }

            function gridlist_cat_desc( $category ) {
                global $woocommerce;
                echo '<div itemprop="description">';
                    echo $category->description;
                echo '</div>';

            }
        }
        $WC_List_Grid = new WC_List_Grid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that issue solved ? because I am not able to find any such kind issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I solved this issue. I used the CSS class: `ul.products.list li.product .price` to change the appearance of the price in list view. The grid view is probably default `ul.products li .price`.
Now all works. Hope this will help also someone who has also problem with it.